# Replace an image with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, image, css, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I've been using [Dropzone.js](http://dropzonejs.com) to allow users to upload images. However, I would like to be able to change the dropzone area to be an image itself.

So, for example, if an article has a "featured image" then a user can simply replace that image by dragging and dropping a new image on top of the current image.

I'm not worried about the backend, just the front end configuration. I've had a look around and there are some similar examples, but I was wondering if it was possible to configure [dropzone.js](http://dropzonejs.com) to do it?

Comment: Use Clickable : that div and preview container should be that div i've done that so its quite easy

Answer (score 0):

1. add css "background-image" to #dropzone
2. add via js/html image into "div#dropzone > form"

1 - is simple
2 - is hardcore, couse need to do alot and test on many browsers